# Avoiding space leaks with `mapM` and `foldM` over `State` monad

Tags: haskell, space-leak

How do I avoid space leaks while using `foldM` and `mapM` over a `State` monad?

Last year's [Advent of Code day 20](https://adventofcode.com/2018/day/20) has a puzzle of generating a map of a maze from instructions on how to walk across it. For instance, the instructions `NN` gives the maze

```
   |
   |
   *
```

(a straight corridor two steps northwards), and the instructions `NNN(EE|WW)S` gives the maze

```
 +-+-+
 | | |
   |
   *
```

(go north a bit, then either go east then south or west then south).

The way I'm trying to solve this involves having a `State` monad, where the state is the `Set` of all the corridor sections (termed `Door`s below), and the value is the list of positions you could be working from.

If you're just following a corridor `Path`, I use `foldM` to walk along it, updating the current position. If you're at a junction, follow each branch of the junction and collect all the positions you end up.

This code produces the correct results on small test inputs, but there's a huge space leak when working on the full example.

Profiling indicates it's spending most of its time in `includeDoor`.

### So, questions.

1. Is there a space leak? If so, where, and how can you tell.
2. How do I fix it?

(I think what's happening is that Haskell isn't strictly adding fully-evaluated `Door`s to the `Set` as soon as it can. In this case, I don't want any laziness anywhere.)

(I parse the input into a bunch of two-element vectors that indicate the step to take for each instruction. That code works fine, and quickly.)

```
import qualified Data.Set as S

import Linear (V2(..))

import Control.Monad.State.Strict
import Control.Monad.Extra (concatMapM)

type Coord = V2 Integer -- x, y, with north and east incresing values (origin a bottom left)
data Door = Door Coord Coord deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)
type Doors = S.Set Door

data MazeSection = Path [Coord] | Junction [Maze] deriving (Show, Eq)
type Maze = [MazeSection]

type Mapper = State Doors [Coord]

makeDoor :: Coord -> Coord -> Door
makeDoor !a !b 
    | a < b = Door a b
    | otherwise = Door b a

emptyMap = S.empty

part1 maze = 
    do 
        let start = V2 0 0
        let doors = execState (mapMaze [start] maze) emptyMap
        print $ length doors

mapMaze :: [Coord] -> Maze -> Mapper
mapMaze !starts !sections =
    foldM (\heres section -> mapMazeSection heres section) starts sections

mapMazeSection :: [Coord] -> MazeSection -> Mapper
mapMazeSection !starts (Junction mazes) = 
    concatMapM (\maze -> mapMaze starts maze) mazes
mapMazeSection !starts (Path steps) = 
    mapM mapPath starts
    where mapPath start = foldM (\here step -> includeDoor here step) start steps

includeDoor :: Coord -> Coord -> State Doors Coord
includeDoor !here !step = 
    do let there = (here + step)
       let door = there `seq` makeDoor here there
       modify' (door `seq` S.insert door)
       return there
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, it wasn't a space leak! It was me failing to deal with some pathological input. Once I sorted out how to handle that, it worked, and very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Space leaks can be very hard to detect in Haskell. I am no expert, but I have heard there are many problems with the State monad and space leaks. I generally avoid `State`/`StateT` and use `IORef`, `MVar` or `TVar` instead, but that would change it to `IO`. The first thing you can try is adding `!` in various let bindings and type definitions.

```hs
data Door = Door !Coord !Coord
data Maze = Path ![Coord] | Junction ![Maze]
```

If that doesn't resolve it, there are some tools that may help you pinpoint where it occurs in this [article](https://ro-che.info/articles/2017-01-10-nested-loop-space-leak).

### Other resources

Here are some other resources that might help.

- [ndmithcell on space leak detection](https://github.com/ndmitchell/spaceleak)
- [Space leak with nested strict StateT](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/7xqfy8/space_leak_with_nested_strict_statet/)
- [Pinpointing space leaks in big programs](http://blog.ezyang.com/2011/06/pinpointing-space-leaks-in-big-programs/)